# Checking duplication using LINQ in collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have function which inserts record in database. I want to make sure that there are no duplicate entries in database. Function first checks if there is query string parameter. If there is, then it acts like edit mode otherwise insert mode. There is a function which can return currently added records in database. I need to check duplication based on two columns before insertion in database.

```
    myService = new myService();
    myFlow mf = new myFlow();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["myflowid"]))
    {
        mf = myService.Getmyflow(Convert.ToInt32(Request["myflowid"]));
    }
    int workcount = 0;
    int.TryParse(txtWorkCount.Text, out workcount);
    mf.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
    mf.Description = txtDescription.Text.Trim();
    mf.FunctionCode = txtFunctioneCode.Text.Trim();
    mf.FunctionType = txtFunctioneType.Text.Trim();
    mf.WorkCount = workcount;

    if (mf.WorkFlowId == 0)
    {
        mf.SortOrder = 0;
        mf.Active = true;
        mf.RecordDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        message = "Saved Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        _editMode = true;
        message = "Update Successfully";
    }
}

int myflowId = mfService.AddEditmyflow(mf);
```

I want to check duplication based on `functiontype` and `functioncode`. Another function `mfService.Getmyflows()` can return currently added records in database.

How can I check duplication using Linq?

Comment: I would suggest using [Entity framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) (as it easier to understand and hundreds of tutorials) to work with database and data in them. Also, I would say that you could use Composite key in your database, which would throw DuplicateKeyException, and could be caught.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what database do you use? Many databases support upsert  behavior (update or insert depending of was data found or not). For example, [`MERGE` in ms sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), [`MERGE` in oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm), [`INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE` in mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and so on. This could be preferred solution. Upsert is usually an atomic operation.

In your particular case do you you transactions? Are you sure no one will insert data after you ensured about duplicates but before you have inserted your record? Example:

```
#1 thread               #2 thread

look for duplicates
...                     look for duplicate
no duplicates found     ...
                        no duplicates found
insert data_1
                        insert data_1
```

This will end up with duplicates you trying to avoid.

According to your code you populating data from GUI and adding only one item.

If you have access to `myService` code you could add method to query item by your two columns, instead of querying all items via `mfService.Getmyflows()` and looking through this collection inside your code. It would be more performant (especially if you have indexes in that columns) and more memory efficient.

And finally, existing of a single element inside collection can be easily done:

```
var alreadyExist = mfService.Getmyflows()
                            .Any(x => x.Column1 == value1 && x.Column2 == value2);
```

Comment: @MachineLearning This is not clear if data context alive while this code executing. For example, it can be created and released inside `Getmyflows` method. Even more, there is nothing states that database accessed via linq-to-sql, entity framework or any other orm. Also there is could be a `TransactionScope` with a `Chaos` isolation level. I have no clue what is going on outside of posted piece of code.